# How to tell Regex that the searched match must be at the beginning or just after tabs?

Tags: regex, tabs, match

I'm fairly new to regex, and I can't seem to get this working:
I did some changes in one of my projects and thus I had to change variable names in multiple files. The variables were named as their class (variable lower case, Class uppercase; I know this was not good practice :D) and this confused me, so I replaced them with getters. 
I want the regex to find every variable that:

1. was at the beginning of the line or just had whitespaces before it
2. was lowercase at the beginning
3. had a dot after it (because a property of it was used)

For example: `song.data` should turn to `getSong().data` while `Song.data` or `this.song` or even `this.song.data` should have stayed the same.

So far I got this regex to work: `/^(song)/mg`.
My problem now is, that most of my lines are beginning with white spaces (tabs) because they are in funtion bodies and I can't find a regex which accepts tabs at the beginning, but doesn't delete them whilest replacing. I hope this makes any sense for some of you ^^

PS: I already replaced all the names by hand, but now I'm curious to find out how it WOULD HAVE worked with regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a positive lookahead/lookbehind that a patern precedes or follows a match without including it in the match

```
(?<=PATERN)MATCH
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/YLvwo9/1)

Comment: your example worked the opposite way I wanted it to work, but I realized because of this, that I need a negative lookbehind! Thank you!
Here's my solution:
https://regex101.com/r/YLvwo9/2